# "service network restart", making eth0 primary instead of eth1

Tags: linux, centos

I have two NICs, eth0 and eth1, how can I make eth0 the primary one?

Everytime i typed "service network restart", eth1 becomes the primary for downloading.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: checkout /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Comment: Are the two connecting to the same network?  Usually network routing rules will dictate which of two interfaces gets used, but if they are redundant, it can generally be a race to determine which gets into the routing tables first.

Comment: different network mostly always eth1 because a "service network restart" will get eth1 as primary...

Comment: When is `eth0` primary? Do you make it primary manually Does it start as primary when you turn the computer on? What are the routes involved?